# Split string into array of characters, keep certain sequence together (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, regex

I have my string:

```
var str = '123\r\nabc';
```

Which I'd like to produce this array:

```
["1", "2", "3", "

", "a", "b", "c"]
```

So, I'm looking to split it by character, but to keep `\r\n` together as one element in the resulting array.

My failed attempts:

```
console.log(str.split(/\r\n|/)); // removes \r\n
console.log(str.split(/\r\n/)); // splits by \r\n
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can’t do this with split alone – `/(\r\n)?/`, for example, would leave `undefined`s in the result – so you’ll need to resort to `match` instead.

```
var result = str.match(/\r\n|[\S\s]/g);
```

where `[\S\s]` is `.` but including newlines. Note that `result` will be `null` on an empty string.

Comment: Excellent, thanks! Yep, went with this in the end: `return (input.match(/\r\n|[\S\s]/g) || [])`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex in split:

```
var str = "123\r\nabc";
console.log( str.split(/(\r\n)?/).filter(Boolean) );
```

- Capture group around `\r\n` will make sure to capture it in the resulting array.
- `filter(Boolean)` is used to filter out undefined elements from array.

**Output:**

```
["1", "2", "3", "
↵", "a", "b", "c"]
```